# Python Dataframe extract list of unique dates from a big datetimeindex of few million rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetimeindex

My data frame has around 17 million rows. The index is DateTime. It is around one-second resolution one-year data. Now I want to extract a list of unique dates from it.

My code:

```
# sample df

df.index = DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01 05:00:00', '2019-10-01 05:00:01',
               '2019-10-01 05:00:05', '2019-10-01 05:00:06',
               '2019-10-01 05:00:08', '2019-10-01 05:00:09',
               '2019-10-01 05:00:12', '2019-10-01 05:00:13',
               '2019-10-01 05:00:15', '2019-10-01 05:00:17',
               ...
               '2020-11-14 19:59:21', '2020-11-14 19:59:23',
               '2020-11-14 19:59:31', '2020-11-14 19:59:32',
               '2020-11-14 19:59:37', '2020-11-14 19:59:38',
               '2020-11-14 19:59:45', '2020-11-14 19:59:46',
               '2020-11-14 19:59:55', '2020-11-14 19:59:56'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', length=17796121, freq=None)
dates = df.index.strftime('&Y-&m-%d').unique()
```

My above code gave the output. But it took around five minutes. Is there any better way by which I can get the dates much faster?

Comment: @Code Different I need some help here. I use these dates again in for loop. like `for i in dates:  auxdf = df.loc[i]` Previously `dates` was in simple string. Now, after your solution, it is in datetime format. How do I produce simple strings of `dates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save `stftime` for when you actually need the strings. It's pretty slow.

Try this:

```
dates = np.unique(dates.date)
```

Comment: It gave the result in 17 seconds. Superfast. Just amazing. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I need some help here. I use these dates again in for loop. like `for i in dates:  auxdf = df.loc[i]` Previously `dates` was in simple string. Now, after your solution, it is in datetime format. How do I produce simple strings of `dates`?

Comment: Avoid loops when dealing with pandas / numpy. Use vectorized code as much as possible. If your concern is only "to make it work", try: `date_str = pd.to_datetime(dates).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'); for i in date_str: ...`

Comment: It is excellent. The time is 18 seconds. It is superfast. I thought extracting string format could take minutes. But not. Thanks again. I consider myself still a beginner. I have to iterate over each day and do some operation. Do you think, the vectorized operation is possible here?

Comment: @Mainland, these comments would make some great questions!

Comment: @MarkHarrison Thanks for that. Which part should I make a new question? I will be happy to do that.